# Spring boot @OneToMany Relationship I can not create new data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a new simple flashcard project. In summary: one user can have many flashcards, so the relationship between user and flashcard is oneToMany. When I try to create a new flashcard, I get the following error:

```
 2023-08-27T09:03:14.399+02:00  WARN 31571 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:503) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:347) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
.
.
.
```

My Java classes are as following:

User.class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userId_generator")
private Integer id;
private String username;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Flashcard> flashcards;

@CreationTimestamp
private Instant createdOn;
@UpdateTimestamp
private Instant updatedOn;
}
```

Flashcard.class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Flashcard {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "flashcardId_generator")
private int id;

private String name;
private String description;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private User user;


}
```

FlashcardController.class:

```
@RestController
public class FlashcardController {
@Autowired
FlashcardRepository flashcardRepository;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

...some code with get method

@PostMapping("/users/{id}/flashcards")
public ResponseEntity<Flashcard> createFlashcard(@PathVariable("id") int userId, @RequestBody       Flashcard flashcard) {
    Flashcard _flashcard = userRepository.findById(userId).map(user -> {
        flashcard.setUser(user);
        return flashcardRepository.save(flashcard);
    }).get();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(_flashcard, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
}
```

When I remove

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Flashcard> flashcards;
```

from the User.class, I can create new flashcards. However, when I send a get request with a userId, I want to see all flashcards that belongs to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code that I can see:

1. There is no transaction around your controller call, and so, you are trying to persist an `Flashcard` entity that is referencing a detached `User`
2. Neither side of the association is marked as `@JsonIgnore`, so JSON serialization fails either with a `StackOverflowError`, if `spring.jpa.open-in-view` is `true`, or with a `LazyInitializationException` otherwise (this is likely the core issue, but I cannot be sure, since the root cause is not included in the stack trace you provided)

A simpler way to do what you want would be:

```
@Transactional
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
@PostMapping("/users/{id}/flashcards")
public Flashcard createFlashcard(@PathVariable("id") int userId, @RequestBody Flashcard flashcard) {
    flashcard.setUser(userRepository.getReferenceById(userId));
    return flashcardRepository.save(flashcard);
}
```

coupled with

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Flashcard> flashcards;
}
```

Since you marked both sides to be lazy, you might need `@JsonIgnore` on both sides.

BTW `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` on `Flashcard.user` doesn't really make sense (what it is saying is 'when one of the user's flashcard is deleted, please delete the entire user as well', which I'm pretty sure is NOT what you intended)